# rule/protactor: how to measure distances to pointer?

Tags: measurement

my first post, be nice please.

I'm trying to measure exact distance from a vertex to center.
It would be better if I would learn how to measure from vertices to pointer,
so I would be able to do a much more kind of measures.

I can match exactly my vertex by enabling rule/protractor and select origin of measure on a vertex by <kbd>LBM</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>..
But I have no idea about how to "lock" the end of measure segment to origin, or another point without verteces or objects.

There's a way to end/start measures from a precise point that not matches with a vertex or other object point?

thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, personally I would try some addon or just using an Empty as a helper to snap the ruler to.

Comment: tank you, an empty could be a good candidate.